# Scaffolding Controller not working in asp.net core 5 in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am new to .net core. With background in NodeJS ecosystem, currently asp.net core feels overwhelming. I am following Microsoft doc for [tutorial to build a simple Web API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio-code), and I am stuck at scaffolding a controller part

I  try to run the following command

```
dotnet aspnet-codegenerator controller -name TodoItemsController -async -api -m TodoItem -dc TodoContext -outDir Controllers
```

but I get the following error

> scaffolding failed.
> no such file or directory

I have tried updating the code-generator with

```
  dotnet tool update dotnet-aspnet-codegenerator -g --version 5.0.2
```

But the end result is still same.

I wonder if asp.net core is just too hard for a newbie or the framework is just too complicated.

Comment: Make suer that in your project there is a folder called **Controllers** ... if Controllers folder is not existed just created a new one with the following command `mkdir Controllers` or create it manually

Comment: @IbramReda Thanks for response. I already have Controllers folder in the root directory but still got that error. Any other reason that could be failing ?